# Android: Kotlin getText: Too Many Arguments

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get a formatted text.
Here is my definition of the text in `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="progress">HMM: %1$d</string>
```

And this is what I call inside an activity:

```
val progress:Int = 57
val progressText = getText(R.string.progress, progress)
```

As a result I am getting compile time exception:

```
Too many arguments for public final fun getText(p0:Int):CharSequence!
```

what is wrong with kotlin, or what do I miss?

Comment: @TimCastelijns or I missed something, and the accepted answer helped me to notice my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getString()` is the method you want. Call it from your Activity instance.